# SQLite Complex query and handling results

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Good evening ( for me ), I'm Emanuele a young android developer.
I want to share with you my problem because I'm not finding a good solution.

I've 3 tables (in reality 5)

```
posts
categories
posts_categories
```

to create the many-to-many relation between posts and categories

I've created a ListFragment to show all my posts with their categories.

So I've created this query ( I don't write all the code :) )

```
SELECT posts._id, posts.post_title, categories.category_name
FROM posts
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_categories
ON posts_categories.post_id=posts.post_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories
ON posts_categories.category_id=categories.category_id;
```

So if I have 2 post with 2 category each that query will return 4 records. Am I wrong?
So in my Cursor I have 4 record but what I really need is to collect datas from the cursor and display only what I really need.

In this case I cannot use a CursorAdapter to display my data because it will insert 4 item in the ListFragment.

And I don't want to load only post and than for each post load categories because if I have 100 posts I will do 1 query to select all posts and 100 query to select categories.

What can I do? I need an expert advice! Which is the best way to handle this situation?
Have you ever faced this problem?

Thank you very much. Emanuele Ricci.

Comment: Got the solution:

SELECT posts._id, posts.title, GROUP_CONCAT(tags._id) AS tags_id, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name) AS tags_name FROM posts LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_tags ON posts_tags.post_id=posts.post_id LEFT OUTER JOIN tags ON posts_tags.tag_id=tags.tag_id GROUP BY posts._id;

Please adapt the query to your problem :)

You can find SQLite documentation about concat(x) and concat(x,separator) here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html

Anyway you can also follow my problem on google group: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/x1r2U8epi4Y/discussion

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you extend ArrayAdapter and provide your own ArrayList with your own Object for each result in your list. The ArrayAdapter provides a function called getView() which should be overridden and customized to inflate and display what you need. That should be all you need.

Comment: Found the solution: comment to my first post :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried CursorAdapter with Filterable. Here is [link] (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/AutoComplete4.html). Hope this help.

Comment: Found the solution: comment to my first post :) Thank you anyway I'll take a look to Filtrable :)